# nodejs app engine app error 413 Request Entity Too Large when upload a file

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I have a nodejs api and one of my endpoints allow the user to upload files (images and pdf), but sometimes pdf are to big (50MB - 100MB) and I get 413 Request Entity Too Large when upload file. I trying to find an configuration to increase the size of the files on my app engine, but can find anythig. Any suggestion of how to solve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Google App Engine, the [incoming payload can only be 32 MB max](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Requests).  It is not configurable.

> **Incoming bandwidth**
>
> The amount of data received by the application from requests. **Each incoming HTTP request can be no larger than 32MB.**
>
> This includes:
>
> - data received by the application in secure requests and non-secure requests
> - uploads to the Blobstore
> - data received in response to HTTP requests by the URL fetch service

Consider allowing your clients to upload directly to Cloud Storage instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what do you mean by “directly to Cloud Storage” without using the node application on app engine?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.